# Displaying a jpeg from a URL in labview

Tags: http, labview

I need to make a labview VI that will display a jpeg image from a URL. (the url is generated based on some data)

I've found a way to display an image from the hard drive (Read JPEG File), so what I probably need is just a way to download it to a temporary file.

All I've found are some low level TCP client VI's. Is there an easier way? If there isn't I can just open a browser window, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this LAVA post](http://tinyurl.com/dmw49v), titled *Downloading an image from a Web server using Datasocket*.
The only disadvantage is that it is not cross-platform, it will only work on Windows, on Linux I have seen this code killing LabVIEW.

The [OpenG Internet Connectivity toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ogic/) has code that is cross-platform.

Ton

Comment: thanks. this is the link to the actual VI: http://forums.lavag.org/post-a10013-Datasocket-Image-Download.vi